# For Wizz Air, is it cheapest to select "travel light" and add cabin baggage or checked baggage later?

Tags: luggage, italy, georgia-country, wizz-air

I noticed the difference in price for "Pack & Save" vs "Travel Light" is €75 in this case. I am thinking that it cannot possibly cost more than €75 to add either a 20kg checked bag or 55x40x23cm hand luggage to an existing "travel light" booking?

Comment: Is this for a (or two) one way flight(s) or for a ticket covering an outgoing and return flight?

Comment: This is for a single flight, Kutaisi to Milan.

Comment: So no return flight, and it's direct.

Comment: In addition, it looks like the Wizz Priority Only option is sold out.

Comment: It’s difficult to say because the price depends on a number of parameters but https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/prices-discounts/all-services-fees tells us that in high season a 20kg checked bag costs between 9 and 95 euros. I would actually expect the price to be the same or more expensive if you add it after the initial booking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment by @jcaron, the cost of adding luggage to your booking can go up to €95 when done while booking the flight.
Airlines tend to ask the same or more for later added luggage, so to answer your implied question:

> I am thinking that it cannot possibly cost more than €75 to add either a 20kg checked bag or 55x40x23cm hand luggage to an existing "travel light" booking?

Yes it can and sometimes does cost more.
As the cost of adding luggage is so variable it will be impossible to predict how much you need to pay, traveling light is the only guaranteed cheep option.
I have never used Wizz Air but I have seen other low cost airlines becoming more expensive than regular airlines when you add all the hidden costs.

Here the complete text and link of the comment:

> It’s difficult to say because the price depends on a number of parameters but  https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/prices-discounts/all-services-fees tells us that in high season a 20kg checked bag costs between 9 and 95 euros. I would actually expect the price to be the same or more expensive if you add it after the initial booking. –
> jcaron